# Mix full-width and half-width figures on a single page

Tags: graphics, positioning, ieeeconf

I'm using the `IEEEconf` class and I would like to put 4 graphics in a single page.

Two of them are very large and will occupy two columns, while two of them are small and occupy a single column.

How can I obtain the following result?

[image]

Doing the following will result in all the figures being one under the other:

```
\documentclass{IEEEconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{center}
\caption{ Empty }
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{center}
\caption{ Empty }
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\caption{ Empty }
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{center}
\caption{ Empty }
\label{fig:4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use a single `figure*` environment. Graphs 1 and 2 can be standalone, with their own `\caption` directives. Graphs 3 and 4 will need to be placed in separate `minipage` environments of width `\columnwidth`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another solution. It differs from Guilherme's solution only in the way the third and fourth graphs are sized and positioned. Observe that the heights of the graphs are set to a value smaller than `\0.333\textheight` as it's necessary to leave some space for the captions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEconf}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for "\includegraphics" macro

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.28\textheight]{example-image}
\caption{ Empty }
\label{fig:1}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.28\textheight]{example-image-a}
\caption{ Empty }
\label{fig:2}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.28\textheight]{example-image-b}
\caption{ Empty }
\label{fig:3}
\end{minipage}
\hfill  % maximize the space between the minipages
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.28\textheight]{example-image-c}
\caption{ Empty }
\label{fig:4}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico - Thanks for the comment and great answer! I'm having a problem with the minipages, in that the images inside have different height (once they occupy full length of a column) and so they are aligned at the bottom, so that the captions for the images start at the same level. Is there a way to align them to the top and have the caption of the shortest image be right below it and not aligned to the other caption?

Comment: @Matteo -- For top-alignment, add the option `[t]` immediately after each instance of `\begin{minipage}` (and before the width indications).

Answer (score 6):

Exactly what Mico said in the comments:

```
\documentclass{IEEEconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{Empty\label{fig:1}}
\vspace{1cm}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{example-image-c}
\caption{Empty\label{fig:2}}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Empty\label{fig:3}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Empty\label{fig:4}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]